# Intrepret the results of the index usage query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have added an index for a table in sql server 2008. I would like to know how much impact the index has on the table and if the index is useful or not.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to (1) measure **before** you make the change and establish a base line, (2) make the change and (3) measure again to see what the impact and the effect (good or bad) is

Comment: Good point @marc_s - hard to test performance changes in a vacuum :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make any measurments prior to making the change?  If you did a baseline measurment prior to modifing the system run the same baseline then compare the results.

Two things the DMVs for indexes can tell use is how much the index is used to satisfy queries and how much it cost to keep an index.  As the ratio (index usage / index) updates gets smaller the more time the DBA should take in deciding if the index is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to tell is to look at execution plans for queries run against the table.

You can look at index usage DMVs but they only tell you how many **queries** used the index.  Whether that is a one-row seek or a 10 million row scan, there's no difference in the recorded stats.

Comment: +1 These DMV are great to get a feel for which indices are really being used - or not. But they can't really tell you how much gain in performance (in percent or milliseconds) you've gotten out of them...